# How do I install a specific version of Chrome on Red Hat Linux?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, wget, redhat

I know to download the lates version, I would use: `​wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm`

But how do I specify a specific major version (such as 74)?

(Note: Using RHEL 7.5)

Comment: RHEL : Unknown version → Please edit your question ..... to include RHEL version + desired chrome version. **Note** : Default is: Add chrome.repo https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-google-chrome-with-yum-on-fedora-red-hat-rhel/

Comment: 74.xxx, etc. etc. older versions  https://github.com/webnicer/chrome-downloads/tree/master/x64.deb

Comment: KnudLarsen, thanks for the list, unfortunately, I need the ".rpm" installer.

Comment: Install `alien` http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/a/alien/alien_8.95.tar.xz ... and convert .deb to rpm : `# alien -r google-chrome-X.xxx`, i.e. Debian packages only are saved on-line.

Comment: By the way, the package `alien` is in the epel.repo : `# yum install alien`